# Dereferencing  a hash value

Tags: perl, hash, reference

This doesn't work:

```
 my %y = ("lkj",34);
 my %i = ("lkj",66);
 my @e = (\%y, \%i);
 my $u = ${%{$e[0]}}{"lkj"};
```

but this does:

```
         my %u = %{$e[0]};
         print $u{"lkj"};
```

If I don't feel like typing that extra line what do i do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the `->` operator:

```
$e[0]->{"lkj"}
```

You can do something similar for arrayrefs, and it's even chainable:

```
my $eref = \@e;
print $eref->[0]->{"lkj"}
```

As a bonus, you can do all the setup in a single line too by using the `{}` shorthand for arrayrefs:

```
my @e = ( { lkj => 34 }, { lkj => 66 } );
```

Comment: `->` can be implied when used between indexes; `$e[0]{lkj}` and `$eref->[0]{lkj}` would work fine.